# Creating simple form using ReactiveForm Modules in Angular 9, But getting formGroup error

Tags: angular9

I am trying to Create one ReactiveFormModule in Angular 9. I have included ReactiveFormModule and FormsModule in app.component.ts. But still While executing the application getting error. Below are the code,

```
**Angular 9.1
Nodejs 12.16**

**app.module.ts**
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
  ....
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule],
  ....
})
export class AppModule { }

**in Home component.html file**
<form [formGroup] = "myForm">
                <input type="text" formControlName = "inputValue" class="form-control" (keyup) = "fnChnageText(myForm.value)" >
            </form>

**in home.component.ts**
myForm : FormGroup;
  inputValue : string;

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
     this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      inputValue : ['',Validators.required]
     });
   }

After running the application getting error - can't bind to the formGroup. How to resolve this. Please help me
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare `inputValue` seperately. 
The `formControlName` you have defined will directly watch inside your `FormBuilder` group and see if it's present.
Also you need to import `FormBuilder` and `Validators` from `@angular/forms`